# Is it possible to assign a table data to a table header in HTML?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I'm working with tables in C# ASP.NET atm displaying data from an API. I have a problem where if a data doesn't exit / null I display nothing

```
                @foreach(var venue in Model.Venues)
                {
                    if(venue.id != location.venueId)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@venue.venueName</td>
                    }
                }
```

If I add (`<td>Null</td>`) inside the if statement where venue.id != location.venueId. I get something like this... Where my table constantly expands until it ends or it finds something. It works perfectly if the data is there.

[image]

If I don't add anything to display as data I get something like this... An empty data which makes sense in every way. But I'm wondering if it is possible to assign table data to a table header so it keeps the empty spot for when the data does exist.

[image]